# CSS properties not applying in nested div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `<div>` within a `<div>` that sits like this [image]

Both containers should have a nice amount of `height` to them, for some reason when I put the `<div>` within the `<div>` it breaks the `height` and some of the other CSS properties so everything ends up looking squashed.

Is `#masthead_topbar` inheriting something from the parent `<div>` or do I need to change something else?

**The Code:**

```css
#container {
  width: 951.8px ;
  height: 600 px ;
  background-color: #c2c2c2 ;
  border: solid 1px ;
  border-color: b8b8b8 ;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  display: flex ;
  align-items: center ;
}
#masthead_topbar {
  width: 929px ;
  min-height: 47.00 px ;
  max-height: 47.00 px ;  
  background-color: #c2c2c2 ;
  border: solid 1px ;
  border-color: b8b8b8 ;
  margin-left: 10px ; 
  margin-right: 10px;   
  margin-top: 10px ;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- Start Masthead TopBar -->
  <div id="masthead_topbar">
    <font>Test</font>
    <!-- End Masthead_TopBar -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Container DIV -->
</div>
```

Comment: well , you just have to remove the space between 600 px ; to be 600px; :)

Comment: Why does `#container` have `display: flex;`? Sidenote: `<font>` has been deprecated since the end of WW II. If not longer.

Comment: `border-color: b8b8b8;`probably should be `border-color: #b8b8b8;`. And that should be assigned to the shorthand property the line above: `border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;`

Comment: It has been a very long time since I have coded in HTML, looks like I have also picked up some bad habits from Java programming!

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of mistakes, such as:

- a space in lengths such as `600 px`
- not using `#` in `border-color` (you can use `border` shorthand)

Note this:

- don't use decimal values in `px` length.
- don't use `font`, it is deprecated.

here is a working example:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 950px; /* changed for demo */
  height: 150px; /* changed for demo */
  border: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.masthead_topbar {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
  margin: 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Start Masthead TopBar -->
  <div class="masthead_topbar">
    Test
    <!-- End Masthead_TopBar -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Container DIV -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well , you just have to remove the space between `600 px ;` to be `600px;`  :)
maybe some other things need to be fixed also (the codes between stars ** ** edited ) :

```
#container {
  width: 951.8px ;
  **height: 600px ;**
  background-color: #c2c2c2 ;
  **border: 1px solid #b8b8b8 ;**
  **border-color: #b8b8b8 ;**
  margin: 0 auto ;
  display: flex ;
  align-items: center ;
}
#masthead_topbar {
  width: 929px ;
  **min-height: 47.00px ;
  max-height: 47.00px ;**  
  background-color: #c2c2c2 ;
  **border: 1px solid #b8b8b8 ;
  border-color: #b8b8b8 ;**
  margin-left: 10px ; 
  margin-right: 10px;   
  margin-top: 10px ;
}
```